# Can AWS Greengrass use a Lambda in the Core if needed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-greengrass

I have an AWS Lambda running on my AWS Greengrass which is the same Lambda I have in the AWS Lambda Core. My question is whether or not I can use the AWS Core to scale my edge capacity horizontally if needed so.

My application is a machine learning application that runs on Greengrass in the edge inside an on-premise IoT server. Can I use Greengrass to forward the request/streams of data to the AWS core so it can use the same Lambda in the Core when the edge capacity is max out?

Comment: You would need a load balancing software on your IoT/Greengrass server to know when to start sending data to the cloud. Then you can use 'Greengrass' data stream manager' to send that data to the cloud: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/manage-data-streams.html
You can then store it in the cloud, run your lambda ML on it or use dedicated AWS ML services.

Comment: Actually, I've decided to create my own load balancing for edge-core IoT deployment with Greengrass. Now, I can finally scale my local Lambdas to the core. I will make it open source and it will soon be published (paper). Thanks!